# Differentiate between hyphen [-] and negative sign [-2.22]

Tags: pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am working in Pentaho kettle version 8.2 and I have JSON Input. Here is extract from JSON.

```
{
  "CEPS": "-6.58",
  "PE": "-2.22",
  "OPM": "-",
  "NPM": "-", 
}
```

In JSON input all columns set as string. So I want to replace value of OPM and NPM with 0. For this I am using "Replace in string" task which replace - with 0 but its replacing negative sign of PE. So can anyone suggest me Regex which fulfill my requirement.

Comment: Those are completely different characters, both in ASCII and Unicode. What you posted doesn't show any hyphens either

Comment: Why replace *anything* ? What is OPM supposed to contain? If `"-"` is a special value, a blanket replacement is the last thing you should do. Although in this specific sample you could replace `"-"` with `"0"` or `""`. It's the ETL tool's job to handle special values and replace them with eg NULL, 0 or something else

Comment: "-" means no data. my target is database table and i can't insert these in numeric column. so my objective replace "-"  with zero.

Comment: In your ETL tool create a task that replaces this with 0, for this field only. Not for the entire string. And even if you don't want to do that, replacing `"-"` with `"0"` will just work, as long as there aren't any other fields where `"-"` has a different meaning. That's a bit of a hack though. All ETL tools allow specifying transformations *for specific fields*

Comment: yes, I am using Pentaho ETL and  using "Replace in string" task. I have to go for Regex which exclude negative numbers like -2.22 and capture only -

Comment: Why do you have to do that at all? Why not parse the JSON data first and convert *specific* fields in a second step, as needed? That's how Pentaho and all ETL tools work - different fields typically have *different* values and rules. Replacing `"-"` risks modifying textual data as well. If you're absolutely sure this will never happen, either now or in the next 10 years, why not just replace `"-"` with `"0"` ?

Comment: BTW for such blanket replacements a simple command-line tool is better than ETL tools like Pentaho. ETL is used to modify *specific fields*, which are far harder (and slower) than a simple grep

Answer (score 0):

how about not using regex and just set like

[find string] [change string]
**"OPM": "-"**  →  **"OPM" : "0"**
**"NPM": "-"**  →  **"NPM" : "0"**

in case you change only 2 key (OPM, NPM)